# Redirecting FTP OUTPUT to separate lines

Tags: shell, unix, ftp

When redirecting FTP OUTPUT to a file, i am getting all the output in a single line. My requirement is if directory is changed or file is listed, everything should be in separate lines instead of single line. Please advise.

```
FTPOUT=`ftp -inv << EOF
open $FTP_SERVER
user $USER_NAME $PASSWORD
cd $FILE_DIR
ascii
nlist ${fileName} $FILE_DIR_LIST
close
bye
EOF` > testfile.txt
```

Current Output sample:

```
 250 Directory successfully changed. 200 Switching to ASCII mode. 227 Entering Passive Mode (165,32,41,174,29,231). 150 Here comes the directory listing. 226 Directory send OK. 221 Goodbye.
```

Expected Output:

```
250 Directory successfully changed. 

200 Switching to ASCII mode. 

227 Entering Passive Mode (165,32,41,174,29,231). 

150 Here comes the directory listing. 

226 Directory send OK. 

221 Goodbye.
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your question, mostly because the formatting is bad. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and edit your question to improve the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

General: Use `$()`, not backtics, for commands.  Use lowercase variable names.
Do not assign the output to a variable and try to redirect is simultaneously (when hou want that, use `tee`).
And use double quotes when echoing a variable with newlines (always use double quotes unless you know a good reason not to use them).
Result:

```
# You should change other variable names too
ftpout=$(ftp -inv << EOF
open ${FTP_SERVER}
user ${USER_NAME} ${PASSWORD}
cd ${FILE_DIR}
ascii
nlist ${fileName} ${FILE_DIR_LIST}
close
bye
EOF
)
echo "${ftpout}"
```